# How to get the indexes of smallest value per row in a DF, as column index and not column name?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like, from a `DataFrame`, to retrieve a `Series` which contains the index of the minimal value per row (so `axis=1`). From the documentation it seems [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) may be useful

Let' take

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [0, 10, 2, 30, 4],
    'col2': [2,  3, 4,  5, 6],
    'col3': [9,  7, 5,  3, 1],
})
```

1. I've managed to get column names of minimal value

   ```
   > df.idxmin(axis=1)
   0    col1
   1    col2
   2    col1
   3    col3
   4    col3
   dtype: object
   ```
2. I've managed to get the index of column of minimal vlaue

   ```
   df.apply(np.argmin, axis=1)
   0    0
   1    1
   2    0
   3    2
   4    2
   dtype: int64
   ```

Is there any better way to obtain the `2.` result using maybe a full-pandas code ?

Comment: What is this for? Some context would help find the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.apply` over axis 1 is generally avoid for performance issues. [*When should I (not) want to use pandas `.apply()` in my code*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

#### 1. [`pd.Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html)

```
cols = df.idxmin(axis=1)
idx = df.columns.get_indexer(cols) # return a numpy array
idx_series = pd.Series(idx, index=df.index)
# Here, index=df.index is important when your DataFrame has custom index values

print(idx_series)
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    2
dtype: int64
```

#### 2. [`df.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) and [`np.ndarray.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmin.html#:%7E:text=Return%20indices%20of%20the%20minimum%20values%20along%20the%20given%20axis%20of%20a.)

```
idx = df.to_numpy().argmin(axis=1) # returns numpy array
idx_series = pd.Series(idx, index=df.index)
print(idx_series)

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    2
dtype: int64
```

---

Some `timeit` benchs

```
from datetime import timedelta
from timeit import timeit

if __name__ == '__main__':

    setup = """
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import randrange
total = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1': [randrange(10000) for i in range(total)],
        'col2': [randrange(10000) for i in range(total)],
        'col3': [randrange(10000) for i in range(total)],
        'col4': [randrange(10000) for i in range(total)],
        'col5': [randrange(10000) for i in range(total)],
        'col6': [randrange(10000) for i in range(total)],
        'col7': [randrange(10000) for i in range(total)],
    })
    """

    for stmt in ["pd.Series(df.to_numpy().argmin(axis=1), index=df.index)",
                 "pd.Series(df.columns.get_indexer(df.idxmin(axis=1)), index=df.index)",
                 "df.apply(np.argmin, axis=1)"]:
        t = timeit(stmt=stmt, setup=setup, number=20)
        print(f"{str(timedelta(seconds=t)):20s}{stmt}")


# Results
0:00:00.012226      pd.Series(df.to_numpy().argmin(axis=1), index=df.index)
0:00:00.408151      pd.Series(df.columns.get_indexer(df.idxmin(axis=1)), index=df.index)
0:00:23.908125      df.apply(np.argmin, axis=1)
```

Comment: Would you like to add some `timeit` examples in your code ? I've made them, you code is amazingly faster

Comment: @azro `df.apply` over axis 1 is not vectorized it's slow and in general it should be used as last resort. Thank you the timeits ;)

Comment: I noticed that I don't need the `pd.Series` cast, I can dircetly do `df['newCol'] = df.to_numpy().argmin(axis=1)` , which is about 5% faster than the same with Series cast :)